# Strategy for teaching in a room that is laid out "wrong"

Tags: teaching

I teach a mixed undergrad/grad course that has lecture (300 people) and seminar (15 people) components. Thankfully for me, only the grad students get seminars. I have 2 TAs that assist with the seminars allowing us to break into 3 five-student 1-instructor discussion groups. The problem is that thanks to the miracle of central time tabling this year I have been given a tiered lecture hall that seats 25 people for the seminars. How do you run discussion groups in a cramped lecture hall?

Comment: You could [pow wow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pow_wow). Sit in a circle on the floor. Or bring in six chairs. Or have them sit beside each other on the front row and you stand in front of them. They could still talk amongst themselves, albeit hindered.

Comment: If the weather's good, just consider getting outside, on a grass somewhere… or around a table at the students' union!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of an opportunity to change the scenery, as F'x mentioned in a comment — going outside or in the student union building and such could be a great alternative.  If you do not have to stay in the assigned seminar room, then why stay there?

To expand on this further, I need to share an example — I used to teach a Physics class, literally in a storage room, it was cramped and did not really help in their learning, my teaching or any of our sanity, so here are a couple of examples of what we did:

- Split the class and did the lesson via a basketball match, we were doing projectile motion — the point here is that we moved location and did an activity within the context of what is being taught at that time.  The activity need not be directly related, but doing a drill (such as basketball shots) of sorts could help students' focus.
- We 'walked and talked', this worked only with small groups — we had a topic, and went for a walk discussing the topic.  This proved to be very effective (for me anyway), as all my students were checking  for information of the topic on their phones etc.

Answer (score 4):

In a tiered lecture hall that has the long continuous tables with chairs, rather than auditorium seats, was the gather students around one end of the long tables and basically have students on one side sitting backwards. The room I did this in has chairs that swivel 360 so this was not actually uncomfortable for them. And then you sit on the end of the table with 2 or 3 students on each side from your point of view. This generally works for small enough groups like you have.